# What should I test in ReactJs applications?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, jestjs

I started to learn better TDD and I am study many articles ...

For example in an article I saw this test code :

```js
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import ProductList from './ProductList';

it('should render a list of products as an unordered list', () => {
  const mockProducts = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Mock Product 1', brand: 'MockBrandA'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Mock Product 2', brand: 'MockBrandB'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Mock Product 3', brand: 'MockBrandC'},
  ];
  const wrapper = shallow(<ProductList products={mockProducts}/>);
  expect(wrapper.find('li').length).toEqual(mockProducts.length);
  // 3
});
```

This is a simple code to test a ul/li list component and this will return 3 , because we have 3 item in the mockProducts array.

So I'm really confused !!!

Really why should we check this code ?!

After each edits programmers will check the results in browser, so why should we write this test and it's essential ?!

For example if I wrote this code, when I saved the code then I will check the result in browser and I will look the result and I know it's ok and this has not bug, so why I should write test code for even simple components ?

It's just essential for CI tools and debug process or it's a different method ? Or maybe it's essential just for know the build seconds and checking the build time ?!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was at some point exactly where you stand, you can read a unit test, but you still don't understand why and how would you know what are you supposed to test. If this is the case, I'll try to explain what I learned.

## The Benefit

Surely testing a component that renders 3 `<li>` sounds silly. When your codebase grows and you have hundreds of components, or when your app has 6 modules, 10 forms and 7 list screens; imagine how long would it take you to make sure everything still work for every little change you do to the codebase. You add 1 line of code and you have to manually test everything? Hell no.

With automatic tests, the testing program will do it for you. You can add 1 line of code and run the tests. You can modify an existing implementation and re-run to see if everything still works.

Basically it gives you FAST regression testing; you don't need to have a QA guy clicking all the buttons to see if anything breaks for every commit you make, but the testing suite will do it for you, and will do it fast.

## What to test?

The simpler answer is **test the output for a particular input**. In "business" words, test the specification. For example, if your component receives 2 props: `hasError` and `products`, you have 3 tests:

1. it renders the error message but no the produc list, when `hasError`  is `true`
2. it renders 3 products when `products` has items, and `hasError` is `false`
3. it renders a message specifiying there are no products yet, when `products` array is blank.

So, for every possible input, you add a test which will check the output is exactly what you expect.

## Conclusion

You will understand the benefit when you have A LOT of components, and a lot of modules in your apps. Testing is one of those things that you can only understand better and get better by practicing. By extension, you have to invest your time writing tests, even if they feel "silly" or "unnecessary". You will see the benefit eventually; there is a reason all big successful tech companies do testing automation, it works.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it really ! But I have a question, we are testing the components with fake data and parameters, so how the edits in others components can affect on another components ? for example we are checking the `<ProductsList />` with fake data and 3 `<li>` item. so how can I check impact of other components on one component with fake data ? thanks

Comment: That's a different kind of testing, you're describing integration testing. The test you have on your example is unit testing, which you basically isolate the component (using mock data, mock dependency) to test it's output. For integration testing, different approaches exist)