# How to test a react web page that takes number of input and generates an output?

Tags: reactjs, testing, web, automated-tests

I have created a web page using react that basically takes a number of inputs and based on these it generates the output. As I am adding new features I want to test my web page for these I have to type in manually all the input and check.

Is there any tool or software that can help me with these.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I test in ReactJs applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374480/what-should-i-test-in-reactjs-applications)

Comment: Or this one https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro